# How to setModel for QListWidget

Tags: python, pyqt

Is there any way to setModel for QListWidget? I am getting `AttributeError: QListWidget.setModel is a private method` on this:

```
class Model(QtCore.QAbstractListModel):
    def __init__(self):
        QtCore.QAbstractListModel.__init__(self)
        self.items=[]
    def rowCount(self, parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        return len(self.items)
    def flags(self,index):
        return QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEditable

view=QtGui.QListWidget()

viewModel=Model()
view.setModel(viewModel)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't think so you can set model for QListWidget. Because QListWidget has its own model. But you can use QListView and you can set your own model to QListView

Answer (score 4):

I simply would like to complete @Achayan's answer: if you have a look at Qt's documentation, you can find [a very good tutorial](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/modelview.html) explaining precisely the difference between

- implementation via standard widgets
- implementation via Model/View

In the first case, the standard widgets **own a version of the data**, which can seem easier to do and manage at first glance, but can lead to problem of **synchronization**. Indeed, if the **widget itself** (which is a view) owns its own version of the data, you have to be sure that this data is synchronized with the database. And what's more, if you have, let's say 2 or 3 others widgets of the **same** model (example: a table, a list and a combobox representing the same entity), therefore you have **four versions** of the data...

The second one is better if you want a more decoupled and flexible implementation: the model is really "simply" a view, and does not own any data. He simply interacts with the model, which therefore has to implement a given interface (`QAbstractItemModel`).

In your case: `QListWidget` is the "standard widget", and `QListView` is the view of the Model/View implementation.